# How check if picklist value contains in Custom metadata in LWC js?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

I'm trying to check if the input selected picklist value exist in custom metadata, then I'm trying to display some records. I have implemented the below code but records are not displaying. Is there any issue in my code?

In `handleNext()` method I'm checking input selected value and custom metadata values but not returning anything on page.

Apex Class:

```java
public without sharing class CaseCreationsController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static Map<String,String> fetchCoverageBucketMetadata(){
        Map<String,String> covBucket = new Map<String,String>(); 
        List<ET_Originating_Area_Coverage_Bucket__mdt> covBucketList = [SELECT Id,
                                                    Description__c,
                                                    Name__c 
                                                    FROM ET_Originating_Area_Coverage_Bucket__mdt];
        if(covBucketList.size() > 0){
            for(ET_Originating_Area_Coverage_Bucket__mdt nft : covBucketList){
                covBucket.put(nft.Name__c, nft.Description__c);
            }
        }
        return covBucket;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List <ET_Coverage_Bucket__mdt> fetchMetaListLwc() {
        List<ET_Coverage_Bucket__mdt> fetchMeta = [SELECT Name__c FROM ET_Coverage_Bucket__mdt];
        return fetchMeta;
    }
}
```

html file

```html
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="EMEA_Request_Template__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="ET_Originator_Area__c" value={pickListVal} 
                                                     onchange={handlePicklistValChange}></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Next" onclick={handleNext}>
        <template if:true={MidCorp}>
            <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={coveragebucketMap} onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                                columns={columnMap} max-row-selection="1" wrap-text-max-lines="3">
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </template> 
    </lightning-button>
</div>
<template>
```

js file

```js
import { LightningElement,track,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import fetchCoverageBucketCustomMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.fetchCoverageBucketMetadata';
import fetchMetaListLwc from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.fetchMetaListLwc';
import ORIGINATOR_AREA from '@salesforce/schema/EMEA_Request_Template__c.ET_Originator_Area__c';

@track MidCorp = false;
@track coveragebucketList = [];
@track coveragebucketMap = [];
@track coveragebucketList1 = [];
            
label = {
    MidCorp
};
            
handlePicklistValChange(event) {
    console.log('Selected Picklist Value: '+event.detail.value);
    this.pickVal = event.detail.value;
    this.EMEA_Request_Template__c.ET_Originator_Area__c = event.target.value;
}

connectedCallback() {
    this.register();
    this.coveragebucketMap = this.coveragebucketMap;
    this.coveragebucketList1 = this.coveragebucketList1;
                
    this._interval = setInterval(() => {  
        this.ischeck = true; 
        clearInterval(this._interval);  
    }, this.progress);
                
}
             
@wire( fetchCoverageBucketCustomMetadata )  
wiredCoverageBucketTeam( { error, data } ) {
    if (data) {
        var conts = data;
        for(var key in conts){
            this.coveragebucketList.push(key);
            this.coveragebucketMap.push({name : key, description : conts[key], hideDefaultActions: 'true'});
        }
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

@wire( fetchMetaListLwc )  
wiredCoverageBucket( { error, data } ) {
    if (data) {
        var conts = data;
        for(var key in conts){
            this.coveragebucketList1.push(key.Name__c);
        }
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

handleNext() {
    if((this.EMEA_Request_Template__c.ET_Originator_Area__c).contains(this.coveragebucketList1)){
        this.MidCorp = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please take some time to read through the [help page on formatting using markdown](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). You used _far too many spaces_, and it made your question unreadable. It took a non-trivial amount of effort to fix your mistakes here. Being disciplined with formatting _and code style_ makes it easier for others to read what you've written. The harder you make it for people to help you, the fewer people you will find that are willing to lend a hand.

Comment: The first thing that I see is that your HTML is incorrect. Take a look at the final two lines. You're closing a non-existent div and opening a new template instead of closing your existing one.